# Pokki Start Menu will not work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

A few days ago, the start menu icon (the little house icon) disappeared on my Taskbar (shown in part A of my image) and I can no longer open the start menu by clicking on the former link.

Clicking the link will bring up the error message shown in B. So I found where the 'Start Menu.lnk' file is located, shown in C. Clearly it is still there, but clicking on it brings up the error message shown in D.

I do a search for 'ServiceHostApp.exe' in on this computer and nothing shows up.
Looking at the Properties file for 'Start Menu.lnk', I see that the target is

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Pokki\Engine\ServiceHostApp.exe /OPEN"menu"`

But if I try to go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Pokki\Engine`, it says that there is no Pokki directory in the local app data directory.

If I uninstall Pokki and then reinstall it, will it fix this?
All I really want is my Start Menu to work again because I pinned all the programs that I use frequently there for easy access since there isn't enough room on the Taskbar for all of them.

My machine is a Lenovo T440s laptop. It is running Windows 8.1.

Any solutions or ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you!

[image: Screen caps to help explain my issue]

Comment: Your problems are caused by a third-party application.  If that third-party application needs to be installed again, you should try that, "the little house icon" is unique to Pokki.

Answer (score 0):

The house icon is **not part of a standard Windows install**.

A little googling finds that this house icon is provided by a third party program:[Pokki Start Menu](
https://www.pokki.com/windows-8-start-menu)

You should reinstall the application or try repairing the install:

1. Open the Control Panel (You can get to it by hitting <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
2. Go under Programs and Features
3. Look for Pokki
4. Right click it
5. Repair

Comment: I did notice that the house icon start menu is provided by Pokki. However, if I go to my Programs and Features, there is nothing with Pokki in the name and nothing even published by Pokki. Yet if I try to reinstall Pokki, it either gives me an error or tells me that it is already installed and I am good to go.

Comment: @e-beth: Then your installation is corrupt and you'll likely need to uninstall the program manually.